# Trying to run two autocomplete queries on one page, both not working together

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Im trying to run two autocomplete jqueries on one page querying from two input boxes.
On there own they work fine, but together, neither work.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>WWW</title>
  <link href="css/page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/div-forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      src = 'actions/auto-complete-makes.asp';
      $("#id-make").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              term: request.term,
            },
            success: function(data) {
              response(data);
            }
          });
        },
        min_length: 2,
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      src = 'actions/auto-complete-models.asp';
      $("#id-model").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
          $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              term: request.term,
              make: $('#id-make').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
              response(data);
            }
          });
        },
        min_length: 2,
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div-form-title">
    <span class="page-title"><b>New I.T. Asset Form</b></span>
  </div>
  <form action="actions/add-it-asset-to-db.asp" name="frmITasset" id="id-frmNewAsset" method="post" onSubmit="return validateNewAsset();">
    <tr>
      <span class="field-name top required">Make</span><br />
      <input type="text" class="form-box-wide" id="id-make" name="frm-make" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" /><br />
      <span class="field-name required">Model</span><br />
      <input type="text" class="form-box-wide" id="id-model" name="frm-model" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Add Asset" id="id-form-submit" class="form-bttnStandard" />
    </tr>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When they are both together, only #id-model works, but on it's own, #id-make works fine.

Any pointers please, as I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Can you please check console for any errors and mentioned it here?

Comment: Two separate `document.ready` handlers which could execute in any order, and a globally scoped `src` variable which needs to simultaneously hold two different values?  At the very least you should combine those handlers and just hard-code that `src` value in the only place you're using it.

Comment: Thanks David, but how would I do that. very new to this. Cheers

Comment: You should use an unique `$(document).ready(function() {`  block.
Any erros in console? If you use only one autocomplete does it work?

Comment: You should mention code of response function as mentioned by @Louys Patrice Bessette and also console error if any.

Comment: @Kashyap: that is from the jQuery autocomplete (jQuery-ui)... That's why I removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

One "ready" wrapper is enought... That isn't the issue.
But two "src" variable are required for two values.

Since the autocompletion occurs when user types something in...
Both urls are needed. You can't use the same variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  src1 = 'actions/auto-complete-makes.asp';

  $("#id-make").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: src1,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term,
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    min_length: 2,
  });

  src2 = 'actions/auto-complete-models.asp';

  $("#id-model").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: src2,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term,
          make: $('#id-make').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    min_length: 2,
  });
}); // ready
```